# Ubuntu 22.04 suddenly minimizes all windows and won't let me open them again

Tags: 22.04

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 and I have the following problem:

While normal usage of my computer, ubuntu suddenly minimizes all current windows. It just minimizes them but is not closing them, so on the dock I can see that the app is still running. If for example a youtube video is playing in firefox, I can still hear the sound after ubuntu minimizes firefox. It looks like this then:
[Firefox is minimized, but it is not closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePAfN.jpg)

When I try to open the firefox window by clicking on the symbol on the dock, nothing happens. Also when I try to start other applications by clicking on them, they start (I can see that on the dock by the orange dot next to the app symbol) but no window is opening. Also if I press the windows key it changes the view but it doesn't show any apps in my workplaces. I can also not right click anymore on the screen, nothing happens if I try to do so. If I press ctrl + alt + t to open the terminal, I can see that terminal symbol on the dock showing up, but there is no window on the screen. My screen is not showing anything anymore, just the jellyfish background. Only the dock and the panel on the top are still working properly.

The only way I can solve this is to log out and log in again. Locking the screen doesn't work. What could I do?

Thanks for your help!

Edit 1: Disabling all extensions doesn't solve the problem.

OS Name: Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS

Graphics: NV138 / Mesa Intel® Iris(R) Plus Graphics (ICL GT2)

Windowing System: X11 (output of `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`)

Comment: To make sure, first disable all custom extensions, log out then back in to see if the problem persists (probably yes). If yes, add information about your system and graphics card to your question (use "edit"). It could be an issue with graphics drivers. Also provide the output of the command `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` so we see whether you run Wayland or Xorg

Comment: I edited my question and added system information. Is that the system information you were looking for or can I add something else?

Comment: That is indeed the information I suggested to add - which does not mean I will be able to track the issue, but others may. It is also important that now we excluded extensions as a possible culprit. Something else worth trying is to temporarily create a new account and see whether the problem there. If it doesn't, then we can exclude graphical drivers or other system wide configuration as a possible problem - the problem is then clearly related to user specific configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem for a long time.
I recommend using the command line, using gsettings to modify hidden settings (‘keys’) from a terminal or other command line app. I consider this the easiest way to enable the “minimize on click” on Ubuntu.

Open a Terminal window and run the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gsettings-ubuntu-schemas
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize
```

Comment: No, that is not the solution. Clicking an icon in the dash should bring a minimized  window in the foreground, also with the default setting.